# NSSound stops working after few hours

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm building an app that suppose to notify some events.
It has audible notification and NSView/HUD notification.

While debugging, I've kept it running for hours. I've noticed that after few hours 8+ the NSSound stops making sounds.

My code is simple and does work during the first few hours:

It runs from:

```
void onStateUpdate(void* context) {
    NSSound* myAwesomeSound = [NSSound soundNamed:existingSoundFile];

    if (myAwesomeSound == nil)
        NSLog(@"\n\nERROR FINDING SOUND!!!?!?!\n\n");
    else
        NSLog(@"Code is being called!");        

    [myAwesomeSound play];
    [myVisualHUD start];

}
```

which is called from by registering CFRunLoopSource:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
        mRunLoopSource = (CFRunLoopSourceRef)IOPSNotificationCreateRunLoopSource(onStateUpdate, (__bridge void *)(self));
        if(mRunLoopSource) {
            CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), mRunLoopSource, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
        }
}
```

This code is coming with HUD code and NSLog of reported events.
So I know that it's actually running as expected but the OS simply "mutes" or ignore the NSSound as it isn't failing.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get it to keep working as this will eventually become a tray app with notifications.

Comment: Can you show the code on how your calling this?

Comment: I've updated my question with more code snippets. There's of course a CFRelease once app is shutting down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after reading some threads such as [this](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/242073-nssound-play-often-fails.html).

I'm afraid to say NSSound is another mixed-result API from Apple :(.

Using [AudioToolbox](https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiotoolbox) is the way to go.
And so far looks that keeps working after hours.

Here is a code snippet (a little ugly but self-explaining about the usage):

```
            NSString *audioFileName = @"MyResourceFileName";
        NSURL *audioURLRef = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:audioFileName
                                                    withExtension:@"mp3"];
        SystemSoundID audioFileId = 0;

        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(
                                         (__bridge CFURLRef) audioURLRef,
                                         &audioFileId
                                         );

        // Plays the audio file using AudioServices...
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(audioFileId);
```

- Remember to import AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h and import IOKit/IOKitLib.h (for iOS I think it is IOKit/UIKit.h and ofcourse include the framework...

Comment: Yes, I've had no end of problems with NSSound; it has tons of bugs, and seems to have different bugs, with different workarounds, in each OS X version.  Great to have this workaround, thanks.

Comment: I'm happy to say I've tested this for 2 days now and it seems to be working as expected!